# hostapd configured with wpa but running with wep

Tags: raspbian, wpa

I have configured my accesspoint as WPA but it shows up as WEP secured on my laptop.

My configuration is:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=AnotherTest
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=testmore
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

What could be causing this?

**Solved**

I was starting hostapd in rc.local as:

```
sudo service hostapd start
```

I replaced this with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hostapd restart
```

It boths starts hostapd, but the replaced command starts it correctly as WPA2 accesspoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try `wpa=3`

Why? Because there is this bug in the hostapd main-scripts that call WEP as a type of the WPA protocol.

I had the same problem and solved it by `WPA=3`

Comment: I have tried WPA=1, WPA=2 and WPA=3 now but it all results in WEP for some reason.